# Adding new items to List obtained from DbSet.ToList

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

The documentation for EFCore (using .NET 5) shows that to add an item, you need to use the underlying `DbSet` directly. However, my current design is as follows:

I have an interface used to obtain an underlying data set:

```cs
public interface IServiceCache
{
    IEnumerable<T> Load<T>();
    void Save<T>(IEnumerable<T> objList);
}
```

This supports access to my underlying cache persistence storage. Originally I only implemented this using a filesystem store, backed by JSON files. I'm now implementing this using `DbContext` so I can keep cache in records in a table in SQLite.

Right now I've implemented it as such:

```cs
internal class DatabaseServiceCache : IServiceCache
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<DatabaseContext> _contextFactory;

    public DatabaseServiceCache(IDbContextFactory<DatabaseContext> contextFactory)
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Load<T>()
    {
        var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        return context.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Save<T>(IEnumerable<T> objList)
    {
        var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        // TODO: What to do with `objList`?
        // Something like this? `context.Set<T>() = objList` (this won't work obviously)
        context.SaveChanges(); // in case elements were modified directly
    }
}
```

And my `DatabaseContext` class:

```cs
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<IdMapping> CacheIdMapping { get; set; }
}
```

So I'd use the `IServiceCache` like so:

```cs
var cache = new DatabaseServiceCache(contextFactory); // assume DI-injected, and that we give it the `contextFactory`
var theList = cache.Load<IdMapping>().ToList();
theList[0].SomeProperty = 100; // modify existing objects
theList.Add(new IdMapping()); // add new objects
cache.Save(theList); // save modified and added items
```

There's likely some compiler errors in my examples; I modified my real code on the fly to trim it down.

So the basic idea is that:

1. I query the database for the complete set of records representing a list of cache items
2. I modify that list and/or add new items to that same list
3. I save out the list, which should include modified and added items.

However, so far I don't think this will work because the only change tracking performed after `ToList()` is modification to existing items. Assuming that statement is correct, my question is:

How can I get the newly added items to be saved back out to the database?

Note that I'm perfectly happy to be told my design needs to change. Originally I designed this with JSON files on disk being my primary use case. So I probably haven't "thought outside the box" and might be trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.

I'm new to EFCore so there also might be some basic concepts I'm missing too.

Comment: All you basically need is `context.Set<T>().Add(newT); context.SaveChanges();`. *Nothing else*. All these components in your code only obscure the path to such simple actions.

Comment: "obscure the path" implies what? That `DbSet` should be propagated everywhere? Separation of concerns seems like a more _positive_ description of what I'm doing, rather than "obscuring". But like I said in my post, I'm happy to be told I'm approaching this wrong from a design perspective. I'm trying to retrofit EFCore into my existing architecture which may not be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the Save (objList) method, your dbContext is brand new and knows nothing about the changes to the list.
One solution is to iterate through all the list objects, reading and updating the entities from db, then SaveChanges ().
Obviously, this is a very bad idea.
DBContext keeps track of entities and all modifications, so if possible try to keep one context object from read-write operations.

Newly added items have primary key = 0. Add them to dbset using the Add or AddRange method.

I assume the JSON file flushes all content overwriting the old one.
In the case of a database, you are working with a record and iterating through all the records is "not necessary".

The context factory is fine, but if all you are doing is sourcing objects, manipulating them, and saving to dbase, you can keep dbcontext as a private field. Initiate them only before reading, but keep open until save.

Another aproach is to implement IServiceCache on the database context.
Than modifications of existing records wiil be surelly tracked by ef, all you have to do is add new objectc to dbset  and than call saveChanges.

sth like that

```
class DatabaseContext: IServiceCache {...}



var cache= contextFactory.Create(..)
..
theList = cache.Load();
..Add();
cache.Save(theList) {

DBSet<T>().AddRange(theList.Where(x=>x.Id == 0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using the factory because of [this advice](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Basically since I'm working in a Blazor Server app, I started using the factory for thread safety. Even though this code is pretty deep/far from the UI layer itself. I assumed I was supposed to create a dbContext instance between method calls. I figured it would be bad to pass DbContext around. I might have bigger design issues than I originally thought. Am I supposed to keep a dbContext as a member and initialize it in the constructor?

Comment: Regarding your latest edit: First, thank you. Secondly, is it OK for a `DbContext` to have business logic like that? I read that while you can have multiple `DbContext` objects, it's probably not a good idea. I wouldn't want to have my `DatabaseContext` implement multiple unrelated interfaces simply because I put all of my database models inside it.

Comment: I don't see the business logic in IServiceCache.
For clarification, your cache has only two responsibilities: return all enitties and save them back.
But of course you know more about use cases and architecture.
Try to save dbcontext as private member first, you will see if it's a good direction.
Your goal is to save changes, so...

Comment: Thanks, I also started reading about the Repository pattern and it's just adding another huge layer of confusion and complexity on top of what I'm doing. I think your idea is a good one, I just wonder if masking a `DbContext` as an `IServiceCache` would raise some eyebrows as an "anti-pattern"; technically though I guess it is a repository just using inheritance instead of composition.

Comment: I assumed the interface is used in a lot of places, so if you want to get your project up and running quickly, this is kind of a shortcut. 
This is not the first and not the last version of the code, believe me.

Comment: For now i cant add comment upper, so 
You started with a file repository and therefore needed your IServiceCache. The stream behaves "linear", so reading all content, modifying it, and dumping it to disk is very common practice.
Don't treat dbset as a collection.
It is almost always (especially a database) query that is executed as needed.
If someone works with databases all the time, IServiceCache at first glance is a kind of quick access object for the most read data.
Gert is right, but dont worry.